# R programming - assigning an index to number the instances of date and character variable

Tags: r, date, counter

I have a data table with two variables, Date and Team:

```
Date <- c("2016-11-20", "2016-11-20", "2016-11-20", "2016-11-21", "2016-11-21", "2016-11-21", "2016-11-22", "2016-11-22", "2016-11-22", "2016-11-22")
Team <- c("NYK", "CLE", "DET", "DET", "ATL", "BRK", "CLE", "DET", "NYK", "TOR")
DT <- data.table(Date, Team)
DT$Date <- as.Date(Date)
```

The data table ends up looking like:

```
    Date       Team
 1: 2016-11-20  NYK
 2: 2016-11-20  CLE
 3: 2016-11-20  DET
 4: 2016-11-21  DET
 5: 2016-11-21  ATL
 6: 2016-11-21  BRK
 7: 2016-11-22  CLE
 8: 2016-11-22  DET
 9: 2016-11-22  NYK
10: 2016-11-22  TOR
```

What I am trying to do is add an index column as to how many times the Team has shown up.  it would look like this:

```
          Date Team  gamenum
 1: 2016-11-20  NYK     1
 2: 2016-11-20  CLE     1
 3: 2016-11-20  DET     1
 4: 2016-11-21  DET     2
 5: 2016-11-21  ATL     1
 6: 2016-11-21  BRK     1
 7: 2016-11-22  CLE     2
 8: 2016-11-22  DET     3
 9: 2016-11-22  NYK     2
10: 2016-11-22  TOR     1
```

I thought the code would look something like what I found in other posts:

```
NewDT <- DT[, ':='(Date = .N, gamenum = 1:.N), by = Team]
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(Date = .N, gamenum = 1:.N), by = Team) : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
```

which I understand means that the classes don't match up, but I can't figure out how to make this work without adding additional, unnecessary data.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
DT$gamenum <- sapply(seq(DT$Team), function(x) sum(DT[1:x,Team] %in% DT[x,Team]))
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not all `data.table` but it works:

```
library(data.table); library(purrr); library(dplyr); library(magrittr)
DT <- fread("ID    Date       Team
 1: 2016-11-20  NYK
            2: 2016-11-20  CLE
            3: 2016-11-20  DET
            4: 2016-11-21  DET
            5: 2016-11-21  ATL
            6: 2016-11-21  BRK
            7: 2016-11-22  CLE
            8: 2016-11-22  DET
            9: 2016-11-22  NYK
            10: 2016-11-22  TOR")
DT$ID %<>% gsub(":", "", .)

DT %>% split(.$Team) %>% 
    purrr::map(~ mutate(., game_num = frank(Date))) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    arrange(as.numeric(ID))

   ID       Date Team game_num
1   1 2016-11-20  NYK        1
2   2 2016-11-20  CLE        1
3   3 2016-11-20  DET        1
4   4 2016-11-21  DET        2
5   5 2016-11-21  ATL        1
6   6 2016-11-21  BRK        1
7   7 2016-11-22  CLE        2
8   8 2016-11-22  DET        3
9   9 2016-11-22  NYK        2
10 10 2016-11-22  TOR        1
```

You could rid yourself of the `df$ID` adjustment if you were happy with `arrange(Date, Team)`, but the order wouldn't have been exactly the same as your desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you want to assign `.N` to `Date`.  You likely meant this where the two added columns are the sequence number and the number of games for that `Team` :

```
DT[, ':='(gamenum = 1:.N, no_of_games = .N), by = Team]
```

giving:

```
> DT
          Date Team gamenum no_of_games
 1: 2016-11-20  NYK       1           2
 2: 2016-11-20  CLE       1           2
 3: 2016-11-20  DET       1           3
 4: 2016-11-21  DET       2           3
 5: 2016-11-21  ATL       1           1
 6: 2016-11-21  BRK       1           1
 7: 2016-11-22  CLE       2           2
 8: 2016-11-22  DET       3           3
 9: 2016-11-22  NYK       2           2
10: 2016-11-22  TOR       1           1
```